# YII Framework - How to load framework in external script [php yii]

Tags: php, yii

I am new to YII Framework and am very impressed by it. I have a requirement where I would have a few php scripts outside the framework folder structure.

And those scripts will need to include the entire framework. How could I do this ?

e.g in wordpress we have

```
wp-load.php
```

Is there is a similar way in YII ?

Answer (score 0):

use `Yii::import()`
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail

but its better to move your files into protected folder.

for example: to include files in protected/test/ folder:

```
Yii::import('application.test.*') //  adds test folder to include path
include('a.php'); // includes 'protected/test/a.php'
```

Comment: I meant it the other way round. I would like to execute "php a.php" and would like a.php to have the YII framework.